# Subtract lists from each other

Tags: r

I am trying to subtract all files contained in one list from all files in another list. I have 64 items in both lists, with the data structured as follows:

```
FUTURE    List of 64

file1 :'data.frame': 240 obs of 4 variables:
..$V1: int [1:240] 1986 1986 1986 1986...
..$V2: int [1:240] 1 2 3 4...
..$V3: int [1:240] 16 15 16 16...
..$V4: int [1:240] 154 118 137 128...
----------------------------------------------
file64:'data.frame': 240 obs of 4 variables:
..$V1: int [1:240] 1986 1986 1986 1986...
..$V2: int [1:240] 1 2 3 4...
..$V3: int [1:240] 16 15 16 16...
..$V4: int [1:240] 122 189 107 114...
----------------------------------------------

    BASE    List of 64

file1 :'data.frame': 240 obs of 4 variables:
..$V1: int [1:240] 1986 1986 1986 1986...
..$V2: int [1:240] 1 2 3 4...
..$V3: int [1:240] 16 15 16 16...
..$V4: int [1:240] 133 178 157 146...
----------------------------------------------
file64:'data.frame': 240 obs of 4 variables:
..$V1: int [1:240] 1986 1986 1986 1986...
..$V2: int [1:240] 1 2 3 4...
..$V3: int [1:240] 16 15 16 16...
..$V4: int [1:240] 125 177 157 133...
----------------------------------------------
```

I simply want to subtract the fourth column ($V4) of all files contained in the BASE list from the same column of all files contained in the FUTURE list.

If these were simple dataframes I could just use:

```
CALC=FUTURE$V4-BASE$V4
```

but of course it is a bit more complicated with lists.

I have tried:

```
CALC=lapply(FUTURE, function(x) x["V4"] - BASE["V4"])
```

but I get the error message:

```
 Error in data.frame(value, row.names = rn, check.names = FALSE, check.rows  = FALSE) :
row names supplied are of the wrong length
```

Any ideas as to how to remedy this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map` to subtract columns from the corresponding `list` elements of 'BASE' and 'FUTURE'.

```
CALC <- setNames(data.frame(Map(function(x, y) x[,4]-y[,4], 
                           BASE, FUTURE)), paste0('V', seq_along(BASE)))
```

---

As the OP had used `lapply`, one way with `lapply` would be to loop through the sequence of one of the `list`, use that index to subset both `lists` and substract the 4th column.

```
lst <- lapply(seq_along(BASE), function(i) BASE[[i]][,4]-FUTURE[[i]][,4])
do.call(cbind, lst)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
BASE <- lapply(1:4, function(i) 
            as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:9, 5*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=5)))
set.seed(48)
FUTURE <- lapply(1:4, function(i) 
    as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:9, 5*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=5)))
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for the incredibly speedy reply @akrun. Your solution works perfectly! I had tried Map(function(x,y){
  x["V4"]-y["V4"]
}, CMIP5.NEAR, CMIP5.BASE) but your solution tidies that up and makes it work perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: If you're not opposed to using a package, `purrr::map2` does this in a very readable manner  - `purrr::map2(BASE, FUTURE, ~ .x - .y)`

Comment: @AkhilNair Thanks, that is some good info.  Never heard about the `purrr` package before.

Answer (score 3):

To further my comment above, a one liner to map the lists on to each other

```
do.call(cbind, purrr::map2(BASE, FUTURE, ~ .x[, 4] - .y[, 4]))
```